# In Kotlin, will a Handler thread wait another thread finish?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I want to record sensor value in every 5ms

But I don't know whether the values are correct if I capture values in other thread. e.g. x is the last value while y and z are previous value

So I write this program to test, if value is wrong, `Log.v("abc not equal", "a:$a b:$b c:$c")` will be called

But the result is no problem, a b c are always equal

Should I trust this result? Why a b c never be different? (e.g. a:10 b:9 c:9), is the Hander waits SensorEventListener finish?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var a=0
    var b=0
    var c=0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        val sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)

        val handler = Handler()
        val run = object : Runnable{
            override fun run() {

                if(!(a == b && b == c)){
                    Log.v("abc not equal", "a:$a b:$b c:$c")
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this,5)
            }

        }
        handler.postDelayed(run,5)
    }

    private val sensorListener = object: SensorEventListener {
        override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {}

        override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
            if(event != null){
                val xRaw = event.values[0]
                val yRaw = event.values[1]
                val zRaw = event.values[2]

                if(a>100){
                    a=0
                    b=0
                    c=0
                }

                a+=1
                slow()
                b+=1
                slow()
                c+=1

            }
        }
    }
    fun slow(){
        var x = 0
        while (x < 50000) {
            x++
            if(x>10) {
                var y = Random().nextInt(x - 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything in your code runs in the UI thread and that is a good thing. "I want to record sensor value in every 5ms" that's what ` SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_*` controls. Don't try to put threads. You can simply skip every other value if there are too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"registerListener()" method has an additional parameter that defines the Handler to be used. You'r not using that additional parameter so the Listener will run all its callback methods ("onSensorChanged()", etc..) in the MainThread/UiThread. Even your "handler" (and the Runnable object) variable is running in the Main/UiThread, so there isn't any problem. Problems could happen if your "registerListener()" method OR/AND the "handler" variable use different Threads.